# Get fragment window token

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I've an FragmentActivity with some fragments that contains EditText.
If I open the keyboard and use my custom navigation (switching the fragments)
the keyboard doesn't closes.

I call that method in activity onCreate:

```
private void initKeyboardHandler(){
        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                          Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(findViewById(android.R.id.content).getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        });
    }
```

After debugging I think the problem is in window token.
Or it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to close the keyboard, get an instance of it:

```
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

Then close it:

```
imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

**EDIT:**

what if you check before this line if imm is not null:

```
if(imm != null)
{
    imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't good for me. It opens each fragment with keyboard on (if it was off). I only need to hide if open.